# How do you send AT GSM commands using python?

Tags: python, modem

How do i send AT GSM commands using python?

Am able to do this quite easily using Delphi and some comport component (TComport), but how do i talk to my modem using python?

Gath

Answer (score 15):

I do it like this with pyserial:

```
import serial

serialPort = serial.Serial(port=1,baudrate=115200,timeout=0,rtscts=0,xonxoff=0)
def sendatcmd(cmd):
    serialPort.write('at'+cmd+'\r')

print 'Loading profile...',
sendatcmd('+npsda=0,2')
```

Then I listen for an answer...

Comment: How do you listen for the answer @c0m4

Comment: @c)m4 with serialPort.read(), I only get okay, not the reponse for the ussd command..

Comment: The litteral string "okay"?

Comment: hmm, multiple errors: there should be no space between the at_command, the other modems weren't responding except one. the pdu convertor was also wrong. I have fix them all now. @c0m4

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is an AT module, but you can use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to communicate with a serial port.